# How to set up a rel=canonical in PHP?

Tags: htaccess, php, redirects

I'm trying to add the `rel=canonical` tag to only one page. In order to add the tag, I need to add it to the  part, in the `mod_header.php` file. This will add the same rel canonical tag to all the pages of my website.

How can I add rel canonical to only one page. I don't want to do a 301 redirect, I want to add a `rel=canonical` tag.

Can this be done with some `.htaccess` code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add to htaccess:

```
<Files "file.html">
Header add Link "<http://www.example.com>;rel=\"canonical\""
</Files>
```

For further info read: https://moz.com/blog/how-to-advanced-relcanonical-http-headers

Comment: i just did that and it seems ok but how do i check if it´s really working?

Comment: Open FireBug or another developertool and check the tab NET (that's the name in FireBug)

Comment: look at the loaded page with developer tools, the go to network->file and look into response header info

Comment: not working. maybe because it´s a dynamic page. is that possible? in that case how i do procced?

Comment: what part isn't working? canonical setting or checking whether the setting would work?

Comment: doesn´t show up any link on the headers response. is that code valid for pages to or just for files or images?

Comment: i updated my post

Comment: i was just reading that. and everything seems fine, but when doing the checking via Firebug there´s no link apearing on the pesponse headers. why?

Comment: such sentences don't provide any helpful info: post website url and htaccess file

Comment: https://www.sobarroso.pt/campanhas `<Files "/campanhas">
Header add Link "<https://www.sobarroso.pt/stand-carros-usados>;rel=\"canonical\""
</Files>`

Comment: try this `<FilesMatch "/campanhas">
Header set Link <https://www.sobarroso.pt/stand-carros-usados>; rel="canonical"'
</FilesMatch>` btw.: your page is available with and without trailing slash: https://www.sobarroso.pt/campanhas/ and https://www.sobarroso.pt/campanhas

Comment: it gives me a Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the original question, in PHP:

```
header('Link: <http://example.com/path/to/page.html>; rel="canonical"');
```